# How limit number of threads in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am newbie in Elastic Search.
When I create the instance Client for the Elastic Search using java, it creates no of threads(around 16 threads).
How I can put limit on number of threads created by Client? 
What will be the pros and cons of changing default settings?
I got some information from this [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/threadpool/).

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the sources, the [TransportClient](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/TransportClient.java#L179) you create to connect to a cluster uses a [ThreadPool](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/threadpool/ThreadPool.java#L97).

So it seems this settings also affect the client side.

This post may give you some insight of how the thread pool can affect your application performances: http://jontai.me/blog/2013/06/esrejectedexecutionexception-rejected-execution-of-messagechannelhandler-requesthandler/

Comment: I tried sending the setting file to TransportClient  # Search thread pool
threadpool.search.size: 1
threadpool.get.size: 2 
# Index thread pool
threadpool.index.size: 1                                          But still it shows me 16 threads in debug console of eclipse